# Searching Lotus notes inbox with Perl

Tags: perl, lotus-notes

I'm trying to search through my inbox to find specific email's but there every time I try and run this script $search is uninitialized/undefined. Is there a problem with the syntax?

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::TypeInfo;

#Create a new NotesSession, which is basically like a new Lotus Notes instance
my $Notes = Win32::OLE->new('Notes.NotesSession') or die "Could not open Lotus Notes";

#Prints the current user of Lotus Notes
print "The current user is $Notes->{UserName}.\n";

#Gets the stuff in the listed Database
my $Database = $Notes->GetDatabase('Server', 'mail.nsf');

# Open the mail
$Database->OpenMail;

# Create a new Document, ie email
my $Document = $Database->CreateDocument;

# Send the email to someone
$Document->{SendTo} = ;
# CC the email to someone 
$Document->{SendCc} = ;
# Subject of the email
$Document->{Subject} = 'Test';

my $date = $Notes->CreateDateTime("Today");
my $today = $date->DateOnly;

my $search = $Database->Search("@Tripwire",$today,5);
print $search->Count;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"@Tripwire" should be: A Notes @function formula that defines the selection criteria. This means that it needs to be a similar string as in a view selection formula. Like Sendto="@TripWire"

Comment: What would be the syntax? i've tried  $Database->Search(Subject = "@Tripwire",$today,5); but i get an error. Should i be using Variants?

Comment: In Lotusscript I would use |Sendto= "@Tripwire"| as the syntax

Comment: Even if you use Perl, the search query has to be written in the syntax Notes/Domino understands. For further help on the Syntax, check your Notes Designer Help, Chapters "Refining a search query using operators" http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/6.5.1/help65_client.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/e71745f2302f974385256dff00622436?OpenDocument or https://domino.mpi-inf.mpg.de/icons/help.htm

For your example above, that would have to be
[Subject] CONTAINS "@Tripwire"

Answer (score 1):

Or you enable full-text searching in your database and use FtSearch instead of Search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Perl programmer, but believe you have additional problems.  The "extended syntax" notation is not supported for setting or accessing NotesItem values via the COM interface.  I.e., your references to $Document->{SendTo}, $Document->{SendCc}, and $Document->{Subject} are incorrect.  You should use $Document->ReplaceItemValue and provide the item name and value as arguments.  Also, SendCC is not the correct item name.  it should be CopyTo.